# AWS data into Excel?

Tags: excel, amazon-web-services, xero-api

I have a client who has asked me to take a look at the spreadsheet that they use for manipulating AWS data in order to import sales invoices into Xero....I'm just wondering if it's possible to directly query AWS from Excel?...this would streamline the process by cutting out the manual AWS export plus I would be able to create a query that puts the data into the format that Xero needs to see.

...moving on from this, I guess the next logical step would be to create an API that Xero can hook up to....unless this is already a thing?

Darren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a sample [Excel VBA / VB6 Helper Routines](https://aws.amazon.com/code/1275) project that might get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go!